# How many MSDTC clustered services (if any) are needed for a multiple-instance SQL Server 2012 cluster?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, sql-server-2012, msdtc

I'm creating a new SQL Server 2012 cluster, running on 2 physical nodes (the O.S. is Windows Server 2012 R2); the cluster will host multiple SQL Server instances; the exact number is yet to be defined, but there will be at least 3 of them.

I'm trying to understand if I need to create a MSDTC clustered service, and if I need more than one of them; so far, there seem to be four possible scenarios:

- No MSDTC clustered service; this is not required anymore.
- A single MSDTC clustered service for the whole cluster.
- A MSDTC clustered service for each SQL Server instance, running in the same cluster group.
- A MSDTC clustered service for each SQL Server instance, running in its own cluster group.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189910(v=sql.110).aspx#MSDTC) is a bit... unclear on the actual requirements, and there are variuos articles and blog posts saying everything and its exact opposite, sometimes *even at the same time*.

How many (if any at all) MSDTC clustered services are needed for this cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You should always cluster MSDTC when using clustered SQL regardless if using SQL FCI or SQL AOAG. I would go for this option as then you have more distribution of the load and they will failover together and run on the same cluster node :

```
A MSDTC clustered service for each SQL Server instance, running in the same cluster group.
```